# USERFORM: Não consigo remover itens da minha ListBox (Error 80004005)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, userform, listbox

Tenho uma ListBox em um UserForm que "reconstruo" baseado em uma TextBox que uso como filtro. A ideia é trazer todos os itens para a lista com RowSource e remover todos os itens que não contém o texto da TextBox. Contudo, ao testar o sistema, me deparo com o erro 80004005 na linha `ListBox1.RemoveItem x`.

```
Private Sub FilterBox_Change()

'Restaurar lista original
    ListBox1.RowSource = "Customers"

' Consolidate a new cuistomer list based on the filter field text
    Dim x As Long
    For x = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not UCase(ListBox1.List(x, 0) & ListBox1.List(x, 1)) Like "*" & UCase(FilterBox.Text) & "*" Then
            ListBox1.RemoveItem x
            End If
        Next x

End Sub
```

[image: Erro]

Não entendo o que estou fazendo de errado. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao popular uma ListBox com a propriedade RowSource vc não consegue editar os itens dentro da lista, especialmente remover um item. Vc precisaria reconstruir a lista com o declaração `.AddItem` para "converter" a lista numa caixa com vários itens, que podem ser movidos, alterados e excluídos. Sugiro para o teuu caso o seguinte:

1. Nomeie uma variável matricial para gravar sua RpwSource original.
2. Esvazie sua ListBox.
3. Repopule-a apenas com os itens que combinam com seu TextBox de pesquisa.

O código deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
Private Sub FilterBox_Change()

'Dimensionar variáveis
    Dim NovaLista() As String
    Dim n           As Integer
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim j           As Integer

'Restaurar lista original
    ListBox1.RowSource = "Customers"

'Carregar conteúdo da lista em variável matricial:
    n = ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    ReDim NovaLista(0 To n, 0 To 1)
    For i = 0 To n
        For j = 0 To 1
            NovaLista(i, j) = ListBox1.List(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

'Limpar conteúdo da lista
    ListBox1.RowSource = Empty
    ListBox1.Clear

'Reconstruir lista adcionando apenas itens que batem com o testo pesquisado
    j = 0
    For i = 0 To n
        If UCase(NovaLista(i, 0) & NovaLista(i, 1)) Like "*" & UCase(FilterBox.Text) & "*" Then
            ListBox1.AddItem
            ListBox1.List(j, 0) = NovaLista(j, 0)
            ListBox1.List(j, 1) = NovaLista(j, 1)
            j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Tash_Riser a linha `ListBox1.List(i, 0) = NovaLista(i, 0)` funcionou pra você mesmo quando o item de pesquisa não está no começo?

Comment: @Marco, realmente estava com problema essa linha. Substitui a variável `i` por uma variável `j` q se altera apenas quando o `If` é atendido.

Answer (score 2):

Não consegui encontrar uma fonte **Microsoft** falando sobre isso, mas quando você define a propriedade `RowSource` de uma `ListBox`, não é possível remover ou adicionar itens na lista.
Então o que você pode fazer é sempre popular a lista de acordo com o que foi digitado.

Segue um exemplo utilizando o mesmo `RowSource` que você providenciou no exemplo:

```
Private Sub FilterBox_Change()
    ' Carrega a lista com base no texto digitado
    ListBox1.List = CarregarLista(ActiveSheet.Range("Customers"), FilterBox.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Carrega a lista completa
    ListBox1.List = CarregarLista(ActiveSheet.Range("Customers"))
End Sub

' Função que retorna um Array com os nomes de um determinado Range nomeado
Private Function CarregarLista(rngNomes As Range, Optional strPesquisa As String) As String()
    Dim rangeCount As Long, cont As Long, nomes() As String

    cont = 0

    ' Atua no range informado no parâmetro
    With rngNomes
        ' Define o tamanho do array com base no tamanho do range
        ReDim Preserve nomes(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1)

        ' Laço que percorre todas as linhas do Range nomeado
        For rangeCount = 1 To .Rows.Count
            ' Caso algum texto seja informado no parâmetro, carrega a lista filtrada
            If strPesquisa <> "" Then
                ' Se o texto informado for parecido com algum nome do range
                If UCase(.Cells(rangeCount, 1) & " " & .Cells(rangeCount, 2)) Like "*" & UCase(strPesquisa) & "*" Then
                    ' Adiciona o nome no array
                    nomes(cont, 0) = .Cells(rangeCount, 1).Value
                    nomes(cont, 1) = .Cells(rangeCount, 2).Value
                    cont = cont + 1
                End If
            Else
                ' Adiciona o nome no array
                nomes(cont, 0) = .Cells(rangeCount, 1).Value
                nomes(cont, 1) = .Cells(rangeCount, 2).Value
                cont = cont + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' Retorno da lista
    CarregarLista = nomes
End Function
```